# What does SettingWithCopyWarning imply

Tags: python, pandas

I tried renaming an index value with the code:

```
df_1.rename({'*****': "Favour Edwards"}, axis = 0, inplace = True)
```

and I got this message:

```
/home/jupyterlab/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4238: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  return super().rename(**kwargs)
```

Although my code still ran without any observable errors, i still checked out the link but unfortunately i'm still pretty new with coding and the vocabulary/ semantics of the documentation seemed sort of complex for me to really understand. Anyone who can break down the meaning in simpler terms?

Comment: This is a clear dupe. But no amount of explanation has made me properly understand this warning; it's spurious in so many cases

Comment: The warning says that `df_1` is a slice of a bigger dataframe. You can't/shouldn't rename it inplace.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I'd simply set **is_copy** flag to **False** to turn off the check for the object as suggested via the link @roganjosh shared.

Answer (score -1):

Its a WARNING not ERROR (big distinction) that your operation may not have worked as expected and that you should check the results.